# DNS CNAME Resolution - which IP would be returned?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, mx-record, cname-record, resolve

I saw this example of a CNAME record, but I don‘t know what IP would be returned and couldn‘t find an answer.

I‘m looking for the IP of `pc2.an.example.com` and the mail server of `an.example.com`

Zone file **example.com**:

```
example.com. IN SOA...

example.com. 1800 IN NS ns1.example.com

an.example.com. 1800 IN NS ns1.an.example.com

ns1.example.com. 1800 IN A 12.34.56.78

ns1.an.example.com. 1800 IN A 123.45.67.1
```

Zone file **an.example.com**:

```
an.example.com. IN SOA...

an.example.com. IN NS ns1.an.example.com

ns1.an.example.com. 1800 IN A 123.45.67.1

an.example.com. MX 10 pc2.an.example.com

pc1.an.example.com. 1800 IN A 123.45.67.2

pc2.an.example.com 1800 IN A 23.45.67.89 

pc2 CNAME pc1.an.example.com.
```

So which IPs would be returned for `pc2` and the mail server? My first idea was that the CNAME would be ignored because `pc2` has an „A“ record with a full IP, but I noticed there is no dot at the end of `pc2.an.example.com`, maybe that has an effect because the adress is relative?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: MX records aren't supposed to point to CNAME records, although I don't think this is enforced widely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd get:

```
an.example.com. IN MX 10 pc2.an.example.com

pc2.an.example.com. IN CNAME pc1.an.example.com.
pc1.an.example.com. IN A 123.45.67.2
```

- There can't exists another resourse record like `A` or `AAAA` with a `CNAME`. They'd get ignored.
- `pc2.an.example.com` without a dot equals `pc2.an.example.com.an.example.com.` for which the `IN A 23.45.67.89` currently is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify, the A record gets ignored and the CNAME record would be used (Got a bit confused with your second point)?

Comment: `CNAME` is specified that way: there should not be an `A` record and it can be considered an error, if there is. The name server should only return the `CNAME` and possibly additionally its `A` record. But you happen to not have a conflicting `A` record, because it's missing `.` and is actually something totally else.